# Total Claim Amount vs Claim Checks Amount

Tags: mortgage, home-insurance

Some damage was done to my house. I received 2 checks from the insurance company:

1. Check payable to me AND the bank in the amoutn of $x to cover damage to the house
2. Check payable to me in the amount of $y to cover damage to my belongings in the house

In order to get check 1 endorsed I need to register a claim with my bank.
The registration form is online [here](https://www.myclaimfunds.com/53/) (I've been visiting the site using Safari since Chrome doesn't load it properly. Once you visit the page, click on "REGISTER YOUR CLAIM").

The form asks for the following information:

[image]

I'm confused as to what to put in these boxes. Do I put:

- Total Claim Amount: $x + $y
- Claim Check(s) Amount: $x

since I'm only asking for check 1 to be endorsed.

Comment: Have you tried contacting your bank and asking?

Comment: I'd definitely ask them, since the TCA might be something different.